# Performing more than one reduction in a single pass

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is the idiom for performing more than one reduction in a single pass of a stream? Is it just to have one big reducer class, even if this violates SRP if more than one type of reduction computation is required?

Comment: Do you have a specific example of the reductions you wish to perform?

Comment: See the `Collectors.summarizingInt` collector for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you want to avoid making multiple passes, as the pipeline stages might be expensive. Or you want to avoid collecting the intermediate values in order to run them through multiple collectors, since the cost of storing all the values might be too high.

As [Brian Goetz noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181682/performing-more-than-one-reduction-in-a-single-pass#comment46586618_29181682), `Collectors.summarizingInt` will collect `int` values and perform multiple reductions on them, returning an aggregate structure called `IntSummaryStatistics`. There are similar collectors for summarizing `double` and `long` values.

Unfortunately these perform only a fixed set of reductions, so if you want to do reductions different from what they do, you have to write your own collector.

Here's a technique for using multiple, unrelated collectors in a single pass. We can use `peek()` to take a crack at every value going through the stream, passing it through undisturbed. The `peek()` operation takes a `Consumer`, so we need a way to adapt a `Collector` to a `Consumer`. The `Consumer` will be the Collector's *accumulator* function. But we also need to call the Collector's *supplier* function and store the object it creates for passing to the *accumulator* function. And we need a way to get the result out of the Collector. To do this, we'll wrap the Collector in a little helper class:

```
public class PeekingCollector<T,A,R> {
    final Collector<T,A,R> collector;
    final A acc;

    public PeekingCollector(Collector<T,A,R> collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        this.acc = collector.supplier().get();
    }

    public Consumer<T> peek() {
        if (collector.characteristics().contains(Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT))
            return t -> collector.accumulator().accept(acc, t);
        else
            return t -> {
                synchronized (this) {
                    collector.accumulator().accept(acc, t);
                }
            };
    }

    public synchronized R get() {
        return collector.finisher().apply(acc);
    }
}
```

To use this, we first have to create the wrapped collector and hang onto it. Then we run the pipeline and call `peek`, passing the wrapped collector. Finally we call `get` on the wrapped collector to get its result. Here's a simple example that filters and sorts some words, while also grouping them by first letter:

```
    List<String> input = Arrays.asList(
        "aardvark", "crocodile", "antelope",
        "buffalo", "bustard", "cockatoo",
        "capybara", "bison", "alligator");

    PeekingCollector<String,?,Map<String,List<String>>> grouper =
        new PeekingCollector<>(groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1)));

    List<String> output = input.stream()
                               .filter(s -> s.length() > 5)
                               .peek(grouper.peek())
                               .sorted()
                               .collect(toList());

    Map<String,List<String>> groups = grouper.get();
    System.out.println(output);
    System.out.println(groups);
```

Output is:

```
[aardvark, alligator, antelope, buffalo, bustard, capybara, cockatoo, crocodile]
{a=[aardvark, antelope, alligator], b=[buffalo, bustard], c=[crocodile, cockatoo, capybara]}
```

It's a bit cumbersome, as you have to write out the generic types for the wrapped collector (which is a bit unusual; they're often all inferred). But if the expense of processing or storing stream values is great enough, perhaps it's worth the trouble.

Finally note that `peek()` can be called from multiple threads if the stream is run in parallel. For this reason non-thread-safe collectors must be protected by a `synchronized` block. If the collector is thread-safe, we needn't synchronize around calling it. To determine this, we check the collector's `CONCURRENT` characteristic. If you run a parallel stream, it's preferable to place a concurrent collector (such as `groupingByConcurrent` or `toConcurrentMap`) within the `peek` operation, otherwise the synchronization within the wrapped collector may cause a bottleneck and slow down the entire stream.